# multi-serial port communication on windows

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am working on a project which need to operate two serial port as the same time on windows, but whatever I try I can only open one serial port. Unless repeat open and close, I can operate the two ports but it is too slow. I need to write and read first port and formalize it by protocol and sent it to another port, but I can not initial two port.  I was using open and close two ports repeatly to do that before but it was toooooooo slow. Anybody know how to open two port in the same time; Thx!!!

here are my code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "udp.h"
#include "Serial.h"
#include "Formalized.h"
using namespace std;

bool sthread = false;
unsigned char status[6] = {};
HANDLE hMutex = NULL;

DWORD WINAPI ULTRAread(LPVOID lpParamter)
{
    Cserial ultra;
    unsigned char input0[7] = { 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE5,0xAC };
    unsigned char input1[7] = { 0x00,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE5,0xE8 };
    unsigned char input2[7] = { 0x00,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE4,0x14 };
    unsigned char input3[7] = { 0x00,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE5,0x60 };
    unsigned char input4[7] = { 0x00,0x05,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE4,0x9C };
    unsigned char input5[7] = { 0x00,0x06,0x00,0x01,0x01,0xE4,0xD8 };
    unsigned char* input[6] = { input0,input1,input2,input3,input4,input5 };
    unsigned char pool[8] = {};

    if (!ultra.Initcom("COM10"))     //ultrasonic COM interface
    {
        cout << "Init ultrasonic failure \n";
        getchar();
        sthread = false;        
    }
    else
    {
        sthread = true;
        for (;;)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (ultra.Write(input[i], 7))
                {
                    ultra.Read(pool, 8);
                }
                switch (pool[5])
                {
                case 0x01:
                    status[i] = 0x01;
                    break;
                case 0x00:
                    status[i] = 0x00;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Sleep(5000);
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    HANDLE uThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ULTRAread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "ultrasonics status");
    Cserial zigbee;
    cUDP UWB;

    char buff[300];
    char data[256];

    if (!UWB.Initial(6685))             //latitude and longitude port
    {
        cout << "UWB Port connecting failure \n";
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "UWB Com connecting success \n";
    }
    if (!zigbee.Initcom("COM7"))       //zigbee  access port
    {
        cout << "Zigbee Initial Failure! \n";
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Zigbee Initial Success! \n";
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        switch (sthread)
        {
        case TRUE:  //ultrasonics trustful
            WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            cout << "1";
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
            break;
        case FALSE:
            cout << "2";
            break;
        }
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    CloseHandle(uThread);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}





#include"Serial.h"

Cserial::Cserial()
{
    hcom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
Cserial::~Cserial()
{

}
bool Cserial::Initcom(LPCSTR Port)
{
    hcom = CreateFile(Port, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING
        , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hcom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "fail serial1\n");
        return false;
    }
    SetupComm(hcom, 1024, 1024);
    DCB dcb;
    GetCommState(hcom, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = 0;
    dcb.StopBits = 1;
    SetCommState(hcom, &dcb);

    COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeouts;
    GetCommTimeouts(hcom, &CommTimeouts);
    CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;

    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hcom, &CommTimeouts))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fail serial2\n");
        return FALSE;

    }
    return true;
}
void Cserial::Uninitcom()
{
    CloseHandle(hcom);
    hcom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

bool Cserial::Clearcom()
{
    PurgeComm(hcom, PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXABORT);
    return TRUE;
}

bool Cserial::Write(unsigned char* buf, int len)
{
    if (hcom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    DWORD dwWrittenLen = 0;
    if (!WriteFile(hcom, buf, len, &dwWrittenLen, NULL))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
bool Cserial::Read(unsigned char* buf, int len)
{
    DWORD dwReadLen = 0;
    if (hcom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!ReadFile(hcom, buf, len, &dwReadLen, NULL))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you open the two? How does the other not working manifest? Also why releasing the mutex after the sleep and not before?

Comment: Once I run , it notes my son thread fail to open port.  Only main thread can open the serial port.  MUTEX was used to shift the owner to operate the status which two ports would refer to.